# Pipe communication in C

Tags: c, process, pipe

I have been working more on pipes and I was wondering if there is a way to read and write in the same process using the pipe.  Here is my code:

```
// Creates 2 pipes per child
    for (i=0; i<atoi(argv[1]); i++) {
        pipe(fd[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++) {
        pid = fork();
        //pipe(fd);
        int r[2];
        int check=0;
        srand(getpid());
        int** Board=build_board(width);
        if(pid < 0) {
            printf("Error");
            exit(1);
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            printf("Child (%d): %d\n", i + 1, getpid());

           // srand(getpid());

            makeMove(Board, 2,r);
            printf("Child R: %d:%d\n", r[0],r[1]);
            display(Board, width, width);

            close(fd[i][0]);

            write(fd[i][1], r, sizeof(r));


         //   play(Board);
            exit(0);
        } else  {
            printf("Parent (%d): %d\n", i + 1, getpid());

            while (1) {

                if (check==0) {

                close(fd[i][1]);
                read(fd[i][0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
                printf("Received string: %d:%d\n", readbuffer[0], readbuffer[1]);

                Board[readbuffer[0]][readbuffer[1]]=2;
                puts("Fixed Board");
                display(Board, width, width);
                check=checkVictory(Board);

                if (check!=0) {
                    puts("Winner");
                    display(Board, width, width);
                    break;
                }

                //srand(getpid());
                AI_move(Board,1,2);
                display(Board, width, width);

                }   
            }
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
```

I am trying to send moves back and forth between the two processes, but with the code I have I get the first move from the child, then the parent just moves until it wins. I believe after the parent moves I have to write back to the child, but I close that ability at the top of the child process. How and I have both communicate with each other until a winner is found and when one is exit.

Here is some sample output:

```
Parent (1): 17291
Child (1): 17293
Child laced peice at: 7,3
Child R: 7:3
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  B  -  -  -  - 
Received string: 7:3
Fixed Board
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  B  -  -  -  - 
Parent placed peice at: 7,5
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  B  -  R  -  - 
Received string: 7:3
Fixed Board
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  B  -  R  -  - 
Parent placed peice at: 6,5
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 -  -  -  B  -  R  -  - 
Received string: 7:3
Fixed Board
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 -  -  -  B  -  R  -  - 
Parent placed peice at: 7,4
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 -  -  -  B  R  R  -  - 
Received string: 7:3
Fixed Board
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 -  -  -  B  R  R  -  - 
Parent placed peice at: 7,0
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 R  -  -  B  R  R  -  - 
Received string: 7:3
Fixed Board
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 R  -  -  B  R  R  -  - 
Parent placed peice at: 7,2
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 R  -  R  B  R  R  -  - 
Received string: 7:3
Fixed Board
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 R  -  R  B  R  R  -  - 
Parent placed peice at: 6,2
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  R  -  -  R  -  - 
 R  -  R  B  R  R  -  - 
Received string: 7:3
Fixed Board
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  R  -  -  R  -  - 
 R  -  R  B  R  R  -  - 
Parent placed peice at: 5,5
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 -  -  R  -  -  R  -  - 
 R  -  R  B  R  R  -  - 
Received string: 7:3
Fixed Board
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 -  -  R  -  -  R  -  - 
 R  -  R  B  R  R  -  - 
Parent placed peice at: 4,5
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 -  -  R  -  -  R  -  - 
 R  -  R  B  R  R  -  - 
Received string: 7:3
Fixed Board
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 -  -  R  -  -  R  -  - 
 R  -  R  B  R  R  -  - 
Winner
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  R  -  - 
 -  -  R  -  -  R  -  - 
 R  -  R  B  R  R  -  -
```

Comment: Don't use `atoi(argv[1])` as the loop bound; use `int num = atoi(argv[1]);` and then use `num` as the limit in the loops.

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but this is just testing it for the final product I would ensure the input was an integer first. then us the way you suggested.

Comment: I'm confused about the role of `argv[1]`.  If it can only be 2, why is it an argument?  If it is not restricted to 2, it means you have many children.  Is the play done by two child processes, or between the parent and one child?

Comment: my argv[1] is the number of processes I want to spawn, I am testing on a small number so I could have put a constant there, but why do that when I would have to change that later. Also, the play is between the parent and the child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the outline of some code that is roughly how I'd implement it.  I assume that the two players will be the parent and child process; I'm not sure how two children would work with the parent.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void err_exit(const char *, ...);
static void be_childish(int fd_in, int fd_out);
static void be_parental(int fd_in, int fd_out);

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int to_child[2];
    int to_parent[2];

    if (pipe(to_child) != 0 || pipe(to_parent) != 0)
        err_exit("Failed to open pipe");
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        err_exit("Failed to fork");

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(to_child[1]);
        close(to_parent[0]);
        be_childish(to_child[0], to_parent[1]);
    }
    else
    {  
        close(to_child[0]);
        close(to_parent[1]);
        be_parental(to_parent[0], to_child[1]);
    }
    return(0);
}

static void be_childish(int fd_in, int fd_out)
{
    srand(getpid());
    char buffer[32];
    ssize_t nbytes;

    while ((nbytes = read(fd_in, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
    {
        /* Process parent's move from buffer */
        /* Write child's move to buffer */
        nbytes = strlen(buffer);
        if (write(fd_out, buffer, nbytes) != nbytes)
            err_exit("Short write from child to parent");
    }
}

static void be_parental(int fd_in, int fd_out)
{
    srand(getpid());
    char buffer[32];
    ssize_t nbytes;

    /* Determine first move */
    nbytes = strlen(buffer);

    if (write(fd_out, buffer, nbytes) != nbytes)
        err_exit("Short write from parent to child");
    while ((nbytes = read(fd_in, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
    {
        /* Process child's move from buffer */
        /* Write parent's move to buffer */
        nbytes = strlen(buffer);
        if (write(fd_out, buffer, nbytes) != nbytes)
            err_exit("Short write from parent to child");
    }
}

static void err_exit(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int errnum = errno;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (errnum != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, " (%d: %s)", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    putc('\n', stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

The `err_exit()` function simplifies error reporting — just one line normally at the point where the error is reported.  You can use endless variations on the theme, but having such functions greatly simplifies the checking for errors.